# updating table columns with arrays, php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have three arrays fetched from input fields(the fields are in a while loop).

```
$act = $_POST["act"];
$apid = $_POST["relate"];
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
```

the arrays $act,$apid,$reason contain values to be updated on each column. for example:

```
$act=(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$apid=(303,304,305,306,307,308);
$reason=(delivery,contract,cargo,offloading,uploading,seal);
```

on the database side, i have the table `ActivityProduct` with 3 columns, namely; `APID`,`Actual`,`Reason`.  `APID` is the primary key of the table.

I'd like to update the columns `Actual` and `Reason` with values from the arrays. Here's my code(that does not work), for the update:

```
$values=array('reas'=>$reason,'actu'=>$act,'ids'=>$apid);
foreach ($values as $key)
{ 
$update_row =mysql_query("UPDATE ActivityProduct SET Actual= '$key['actu']}',Reason='{$key['reas']}' WHERE APID='{$key['ids']}'  " )
}
```

Here's the error i'm getting:

```
Notice: Undefined index: actu in C:\xampp\htdocs\PD\validate\save-actual.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined index: reas in C:\xampp\htdocs\PD\validate\save-actual.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined index: ids in C:\xampp\htdocs\PD\validate\save-actual.php on line 65
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong? or how to make it work?.....i'm not that familiar with arrays.

Comment: Why do you use `foreach`? You already have three values which can be put into query, why put them in array?

Comment: @u_mulder is correct and also your $key is actually your array value.

Comment: @u_mulder  may be it's possible that he shows only a example and he is getting multiple-one. Actually can't say , Because it's unclear form OP's side

Comment: you are also missing an opening curly brace from `Actual=$key..` and using the deprecated `mysql_query` function

Comment: the problem is that each array contains values for only one table column, and not the three columns. for example: instead of an array containing values: `1`,`i am not familiar with arrays`,`303`.  it contains values:`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`

Answer (score 0):

```
It should be like this,remove the for loop

   $values=array('reas'=>$reason,'actu'=>$act,'ids'=>$apid);

   $update_row =mysql_query("UPDATE ActivityProduct SET Actual= '".$values['actu']."',Reason='".$values['reas']."' WHERE APID='".$values['ids']."'");
```

Comment: Again, missing the opening curly brace from `Actual= $key['actu']}`

Comment: Please don't use string interpolation for building SQL queries, especially if the content of the variables comes from the user (`$_POST`). It opens you up to SQL injections.

Comment: i'm getting an error:  "Notice: Array to string conversion..."

Answer (score 0):

They $key variable is not array, try to print it in loop and you will see.
And check [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and examples of foreach loop to be familiar with it.

You don't need this loop anyway, remove loop and try this

```
$update_row =mysql_query("UPDATE ActivityProduct SET Actual= {$values['actu']},Reason='{$values['reas']}' WHERE APID='{$values['ids']}'  " )
```

If you will run this foreach you update will be executed 3 times because you have 3 items in array.

Comment: using your method, i'm getting an error on the query: Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: Again, missing the opening curly brace from `Actual= $values['actu']}`

Comment: Kenn, try to print (var_dump) your $values['actu'] and then get actual value of it.