# updating database table columns with array values in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i had asked this question,earlier: [question]: [updating table columns with arrays, php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609422/updating-table-columns-with-arrays-php) though i did not get an appropriate solution.

So, i came accross this code(that works):

```
$values = Array (
                 Array ( 'entry_id' => 41142, 'test2' => 124, 'lev' => 'Jah'), 
                 Array ( 'entry_id' => 41103, 'test2' => 1286634, 'lev' => 'Jaja'),
                 Array ( 'entry_id' => 41100, 'test2' => 1234, 'lev' => 'Ja')
               );

foreach ($values as $key)
{
   $sql_update = mysql_query("UPDATE arr set test2 ={$key['test2']},lev ='{$key['lev']}'  where entry_id = '{$key['entry_id']}'");
}
```

now, my problem is that i have 3 arrays, that i'd like to update a database table columns with the values they hold. Below is an example of my arrays:

```
$apid=array(1,2,3,4);
$act=array(303,304,305,306);
$reason=array('delivery','contract','cargo','offloading');
```

Here's my table
[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bHlM.jpg)

here's how i'd like the records to appear, in the table, after the update.
[databasetable after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bHlM.jpg)
here's my code for update

```
//getting values from form
$apid = $_POST["relate"];
act = $_POST["act"];
$reason = $_POST['reason'];

$values=array('reas'=>$reason,'actu'=>$act,'ids'=>$apid);

//the below code is us suggested, by one of the users, on my earlier post
$update_row =mysql_query("UPDATE ActivityProduct SET Actual= '{$values['actu']}',Reason='{$values['reas']}' WHERE APID='{$values['ids']}' ");
```

below is the error i'm getting:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PD\validate\save-actual.php on line 66
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PD\validate\save-actual.php on line 66
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PD\validate\save-actual.php on line 66
```

line 66 is the one with the update statement.

i hate to admit it, but i am stuck here. Please help!

Comment: Its hard to understand your question, also your "database table" and "databasetable after update" are one and the same

Comment: or if you are just worried about the error then just update your code with this: `$update_row =mysql_query("UPDATE ActivityProduct SET Actual= '" . $values['actu'] . "',Reason='" . $values['reas'] . "' WHERE APID='" . $values['ids'] . "' ");` this might resolve your error.

Comment: the database tables are the same..i'm just trying to show how i'd like the values on the arrays, stored in the table...

Comment: still the same error

Comment: @Kenn you forgot to put $ in front of act = $_POST["act"];

Comment: @KiranMuralee i think that will give "undefined constant" error.